# InvalidArgumentException - Magento functional Testing

Tags: magento2

I am executing the functional test for custom module.
I am getting below error.

> Namespace\Module\Test\TestCase\CreatePincodeEntityTest::test with data set "CreatePincodeEntityTestVariation1" (CreatePincodeEntityTestVariation1)
>   InvalidArgumentException: Cannot generate class "Namespace\Module\Test\Block\Adminhtml\Pincode\Edit\PincodeForm". Unknown type block
>   in /dev/tests/functional/vendor/magento/mtf/Magento/Mtf/Code/Generator.php:62

How to solve the above error.

If i run generate.php, getting same error.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you have error in your block namespace. Check if your block is located in `\Namespace\Module\Test\Block\Adminhtml\Pincode\Edit\PincodeForm`. Probably this block has another namespace.

Same issue here: https://github.com/magento/mtf/issues/23